# python3:list assignment index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
 def enque(self,data):
        if (self.end==self.msize-1 & self.front==0):
            print('Q is full')

        elif self.front==-1:
            self.front=0
            self.end=0
            self.q[self.end]=data
```

Comment: Add a question, please.

Comment: Also, your function is displayed incorrectly. Try indenting `def enque(self,data)` by 3 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the length of `self.q` (i.e. `len(self.q))`) and I think you will see that the length is `0`. For there to be a `0` index in the list (i.e. `self.q[0]`), you would expect to see a `self.q` length of 1. Since the list has no index `0`, you cannot write a value.

Instead of specifying an index position value that doesn't exist directly, try to `append` the value to the list.

```py
 def enque(self,data):
        if (self.end==self.msize-1 & self.front==0):
            print('Q is full')

        elif self.front==-1:
            self.front=0
            self.end=0
            #self.q[self.end]=data
            self.q.append(data)
```

Note, `append` will always put the data at the end of the list. If `self.q` already had some other values, appending would not result in your data being placed in index 0.

If you want to always put it in index 0 (if it exists) or create index 0 (if it doesn't exist), you could instead do something like:

```py
    if self.q: # only non-empty list will pass
        self.q[self.end] = data
    else:      # empty list
        self.q.append(data)
```